# Responsive background image: How to handle height?

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have a banner with a background image like so:

```
<section id="banner" class="container" style="background:url(http://placehold.it/1170x200) no-repeat center 
center; background-size: 100% auto; height: 200px;">
</section>
```

I want to have the background image be responsive and adjust its height accordingly, but as you can see...I have height set to 200px as the initial point so we can see the image. I know this is not right, but I am unsure how to have the height set to 'auto' as simply writing "height: auto" does not work.

How would I fix this? [Live code here](http://ogmda.com/asc/about.php).

Comment: this depends on what you want the height to do relative to the width - are you trying to maintain the aspect ratio of the original image? do you want it to simply maintain the same height? do you want it to be guided by the size of the container or is the container there simply to be able to display the background-image as a background?

Comment: Good questions. I just want to keep the aspect ratio. Don't need the same height. Yes, the container is there to simply display the background-image as a background.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the desired result, you can use the background property `cover` or `contain`.
Fiddle for demonstrating the difference [CSS Background Cover vs Contain](http://jsfiddle.net/matthias_h/32yxuq2y/)
Difference is that `cover` will scale the image as small as possible while `contain` will scale it to be as large as possible. As you would like to scale the height, `contain` should work for you.

```
 <section id="banner-contain" class="container"></section>
 <section id="banner-cover" class="container"></section>

#banner-contain.container {
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/1170x200);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  -moz-background-size: contain;
  height: 200px;
}
#banner-cover.container {
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/1170x200);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
  height: 200px;
}
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

Answer (score 0):

Did something like this :

```
<section class="container">
  <img class="test" src="http://placehold.it/1170x200">
</section>

.test{
   height: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   margin-left: auto;
   max-width: 100%;
}
```